# How to convert text to a decimal/double in Swift after replacingOccurences?

Tags: swift

I am at a loss for how I can take a string and convert it to a float, double or decimal after placing some text. For some context, I have a string `var test = "$50.50"` and I did the following:

```
var denominator: Int = 5
var newStr = Decimal(test.replacingOccurrences(of: "$", with: "")) / Decimal(denominator)
```

I keep getting errors like:

> Cannot convert value of type 'Float?' to expected argument type 'Decimal'

I tried changing the wrapper to be Float, etc. and I just keep getting errors... what is the proper way to do this? I feel like I must be making it harder than it is, using other languages like javascript make this a very easy/simple task.

Comment: What exactly do you want as the result? The `Decimal` 10.1? Also, it seems like your real code is something like `Float(test.replacingOccurrences(of: "$", with: "")) / Decimal(denominator)`, as I can't reproduce your error message with the code provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert string to double or float value first like following

```
var test = "$50.50"
var denominator:Int = 5
var v = test.replacingOccurrences(of: "$", with: "")
var newStr = Decimal(Double(v) ?? 0)/Decimal(denominator)
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Because u can cast it from different types [like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMoc9.png), in Your case:

```
Decimal(string: <#T##String#>)
Decimal(<#T##value: Int##Int#>)
```

Then solution:

```
var test = "$50.50"

var denominator:Int = 5
var newStr = (Decimal(string: test.replacingOccurrences(of: "$", with: "")) ?? 0) / Decimal(denominator)
print(newStr)
```

output: "10.1"

Comment: You should also pass an appropriate `locale` parameter, as different locales use different characters as the decimal separator, and may parse the `.` in `50.50` differently.